# Como ver as queries que foram executadas pelo eloquent em Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Como posso descobrir quais queries foram executadas no Laravel?

Por exemplo, eu tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$usuarios = Usuario::with('nivel')->where(['status' => 1])->get();
```

Gostaria de saber quais foram as consultas executadas. Tem como fazer um log disso no Laravel?

Gostaria de incluir o Laravel 5 e 4 nas respostas, pois eu costumo utilizar os dois.

Comment: Experimente colocar `...->toSql()` em vez de `...->get()`. Será isso?

Comment: Mas isso não vai fazer a consulta.  Isso vai converter a consulta do `Model` em uma string de SQL. Eu quero continuar rodando o `Get()` e descobrir todas as queries que foram executadas nas páginas.

Comment: Nunca fiz isso, e não quero arriscar a responder sem testar. Veja se isto ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4

Comment: Funciona, Miguel. Fiz essa pergunta para dar oportunidade para alguém responder mesmo. Eu já sabia a resposta. Você deve executar `DB::enableQueryLog` antes das consultas. Daí, a partir da consulta que você quer capturar o `log`, você chama ele antes. Então, no final de todas as consultas voce chama `getQueryLog` para capturar eles.

Comment: Pode responder, jovem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em Laravel 4 pode fazer:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); // array de todas as queries que foram corridas
```

Já em Laravel 5, visto que o log [não está ativo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e0abfe5c49d225567cb4dfd56df9ef05cc297448) por default e temos de ativa-lo:

```
use DB;
...
DB::enableQueryLog();
...
$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); // array de todas as queries que foram corridas
```

Ainda em Laravel 5, se tiver  multiplas bases de dados e só quiser ativar o log para uma delas (uma das conecções):

```
DB::connection('connection')->enableQueryLog();
```

#### Onde colocar esta ativação?

Isto pode ser colocado em um [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) que entra em acção em alguma/algumas requisições, de maneira a que tudo o que seja feito (queries neste caso) no resto da requisição fique guardado, e finalmente podemos usar o metodo [terminate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#terminable-middleware) para recuperar as queries armazenadas:

```
class AntesDeQualquerQuery
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        DB::enableQueryLog();
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        // dump de todas as queries no termino de execução deste middleware
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    }
}
```

Podemos também colocar isto no ficheiro `bootstrap/app.php`, assim cada vez que o artisan (CLI) entra em acção isto fica logo à partida definido:

```
$app['events']->listen('artisan.start', function(){
    \DB::enableQueryLog();
});
```

Caso precisemos do logo somente no local e não em produção:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // Se for local queremos ativar o log
    DB::enableQueryLog();
}
```

[DOCUMENTAÇÃO](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

Comment: Parabéns, jovem. Caprichou na resposta :D +1

Comment: Um adendo: No Laravel 4, não precisa usar o `use DB`, já que não tem  `namespace`.

Comment: Foi um bocado adaptada de uma que me pareceu boa do SOen. Obgado @WallaceMaxters

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depende, nada impede que a pessoa use namespaces no seu código.

Comment: Sim @gmsantos, mas por default laravel 4 não usa, acho que não valia a pena escalar a resposta até esse ponto

Comment: @gmsantos sim, isso vai depender da pessoa querer usar sim. Eu mesmo já usei numa aplicação em Laravel 4, mas é bem raro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters para que fique registado, eu acho que é uma boa pergunta eu próprio vou usar este log sempre que necessário. Já gastei os meus votos de hoje mas amanhã vou colocar +1 na pergunta que acho que é util para quem usa Laravel

Comment: @Miguel é que da forma que foi colocado dá a impressão que o Laravel 4 não trabalha com namespaces, o que não é verdade.

Comment: Claro @gmsantos , talvez o framework por default não use, mas se php permite então pode ;)

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de ver as *queries* executadas por uma requisição diretamente no navegar é através do [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

Ele é compatível com o Laravel 4 e 5, e tem uma aba que mostra todas as *queries*. Inclusive tem uma configuração que pode incluir também o *execution plan* daquela query.

[image: Laravel Debugbar]

Comment: Bacana esse plugin +1