# Laravel como realizar consulta no banco aplicando "exceções" com relacionamento?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento, modelo-relacional

Preciso pegar todos os usuários com "`Exceção`" os que forem da função que contem o `id=2`, é possível?

Tem como encaixar um `Where` nessa consulta?

Eu tenho a seguinte consultar no banco `Laravel` que retorna um objeto para o `datatables.net` segue consulta:

```
$query = User::query()->select('*');
$query->with(['roles']);
$table = Datatables::of($query);
```

Isso me retornas todos os usuários do banco e com suas respectivas funções 'roles'.
se eu quero buscar todos de uma determinada função eu faço isso:

```
$query = Role::find(1)->users;
$table = Datatables::of($query);
```

O '1' dentro de `find()`  representa o `id` da função

```
find(1)
```

porém eu preciso pegar todos os usuários de todas as funções ***Exceto*** a do `id = 2` é possível?

Comment: as funções é da `Roles` ???

Comment: sim, do jeito que está no exemplo

Comment: Veja bem essa query: $query = User::query()->select('*'); $query->with(['roles']); ela me retorna todos os usuários de todas as Roles porém eu quero que ela retorne todos os usuários exceto os da role 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

Todos os `Role` *exceto* o número **2** traga a relação de `usuários`, ***exemplo***

```
$users = Role::where('id', '<>', 2)->users;
```

trazendo todos os usuários exceto o que tem `roles == 2`.

***Observação:*** `users` e a sua relação com as funções de cada usuário então coloque o mesmo nome configurado no seu `model`

Um outra forma pela relação do usuário com o método [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$users = User::with(['roles'])->has('roles', '<>', 2)->get();
```

<sup>Referencia: [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)</sup>

Comment: Era isso!
Obrigado!!

Comment: Cara, testei e não funcionou seu método.

Comment: Veja bem essa query:  $query = User::query()->select('*');
            $query->with(['roles']);
ela me retorna todos os usuários de todas as Roles porém eu quero que ela retorne todos os usuários exceto os da role 1

Comment: @Rafael voce fez igual está no meu exemplo, não pode separar?

Comment: @Rafael é um builder se não pode separar porque aí não guarda o estado como deveria. Presta atenção no meu exemplo...

Comment: Desculpe  @Virgilio Novic mas continuo sem intender :/

Comment: @Rafael não pode separar os comandos é igual está na resposta. Entendeu?

Comment: Eu entendi, eu fiz isso mas não funcionou. ele me retornou todos os usuários. de todas as funções "roles" e no meu caso eu queria tirar os da Role com ID 1

Comment: @Rafael funciona sim você está fazendo algo de errado. Edite a sua pergunta e coloque o que você fez. Funciona sim.

Comment: Tira o query() @Rafael  não pode ter esse cara aí a pergunta foi editada

Comment: @Rafael eu fiz um exemplo minimo e é isso mesmo ... Se tiver algum problema edite a sua pergunta explicando o passo a passo que você o fez ... Aqui no site já foi respondido uma forma de debugar a SQL gerada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148766/como-ver-as-queries-que-foram-executadas-pelo-eloquent-em-laravel , utilize para ver se as suas SQL estão corretas e a sua relação de banco também