# Como sobreescrever o método run de Illuminate\Database\Connection.php do laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

Preciso customizar a chamada da função de callback no método run() da classe Connection.php, localizada em laravel\frameword\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

O problema é que ela se encontra na pasta vendor do projeto, o que significa que não é o melhor local para efetuar a alteração.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como posso fazer isso? O projeto contém várias classes e inúmeras operações de consultas espalhadas dentro do projeto. E como agora precisamos alterar as chamadas para API, o melhor local para alterar é neste método [run()]. A linha comentada

```
// $result = $this->runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, $callback);
```

contém a chamada original do pacote. Minha alteração é para a função de chamada para API, que já devolve os dados similarmente ao "runQueryCallbck"

```
$result = execSqlApiFirebird($query);
```

Aqui é o método completo:

```
/**
 * Run a SQL statement and log its execution context.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array  $bindings
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException
 */
protected function run($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
{
    $this->reconnectIfMissingConnection();

    $start = microtime(true);

    // Here we will run this query. If an exception occurs we'll determine if it was
    // caused by a connection that has been lost. If that is the cause, we'll try
    // to re-establish connection and re-run the query with a fresh connection.
    try {
        $query = str_replace(array('?'), array('\'%s\''), $query);
        $query = vsprintf($query, $bindings);
        // dump($query);
        // $result = $this->runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, $callback);
        $result = execSqlApiFirebird($query);
        // dd($result);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        $result = $this->handleQueryException(
            $e, $query, $bindings, $callback
        );
    }

    // Once we have run the query we will calculate the time that it took to run and
    // then log the query, bindings, and execution time so we will report them on
    // the event that the developer needs them. We'll log time in milliseconds.
    $this->logQuery(
        $query, $bindings, $this->getElapsedTime($start)
    );
    // dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Bom se tiver lógica isso que você precisa fazer, é com herança geralmente os pacotes fazem esse tipo de abordabem e na classe que herda reescrevem os métodos ou até criam novos, mas, eu queria saber o seguinte, porque está querendo fazer isso?

Comment: Considerando o tamanho do projeto, teria que refazer muita consulta. Eu imagino que deva dar para rescrever o método run() dessa classe de alguma forma que não seja uma baita gambiarra dessas. O objetivo seria interceptar todas as consultas em SQL e enviar para API e configurar o retorno, conforme a função já faz. Eu não sei como fazer isso, estou há dias nesse problema... Talvez, não sei, mas eu esteja perdendo tempo querendo encurtar o trabalho de refazer tudo... O que acha? Conhece alguma forma de mudar o comportamento sem ser gambiarra?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148766/como-ver-as-queries-que-foram-executadas-pelo-eloquent-em-laravel dá uma olhada nisso!

Comment: tentei ver se conseguia fazer algo, mas a mecânica mais técnica do laravel é bem complexa para mim... A idéia de usar middleware é sensacional, mas não tenho a mínima idéia de como manipular a conexão mesmo

Comment: o complicado é saber o que exatamente você deseja fazer, a sua pergunta abre muitos pontos.

Comment: Na API eu envio o sql inteiro a ser executado, de maneira que o projeto pode ter sido construído em firebird, mysql, postgresql, etc... Com isso, não será mais necessário configurar database no sistema. Apenas envia requisição para api, que retorna os dados. Para isso funcionar, preciso modificar a função run(), que ao invés de executar "$result = $this->runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, $callback);", executa "$result = execSqlApiFirebird($query);". Mas esta alteração está sendo feita no local errado...

Comment: Não sei se consegui explicar certo, mas é basicamente isso: interceptar o estágio final da consulta, com sql montado no ponto de executar no banco, mas executar a chamada na API... Não consegui encontrar uma resposta, por isso, enquanto isso, estou alterando as chamadas nos Controllers... Estou fazendo do jeito doloroso...

Comment: Você quer mandar somente a SQL? no resultado da sua API?

Comment: isso, por exemplo: DB::table("products")->get() === "select * from products"
então vai montar até chegar na função run() e enviar este sql para api, que trará os dados do mesmo jeito que traria normalmente. A API está pronta. Essa modificação no metodo run() que está me quebrando as pernas

Comment: se sabe que tem o toSql()? exemplo `User::where('id', 1)->toSql()`?

Comment: sim, esse seria o jeito que comecei a fazer... O jeito demorado... Tem muitas chamadas para fazer isso, sem falar que se vc fizer: User::where(xxx, xxx)->count(), não temos o toSql(), o que significa mais demanda... Acredita que estou fazendo o certo? Refazer todas as chamadas, fazendo: execSqlApiFirebird(User::where('id', 1)->toSql())...
Ou seja, modificar praticamente isso em umas 50 mil linhas

Comment: Sinceridade não sei se você está certo e também eu não sei porque precisa somente das SQL? porque precisa?

Comment: a api recebe o sql completo... Os projetos, em alguns casos, são disponibilizados no lado Cliente, com código fonte ofuscado. Acontece que em alguns casos, a conexão PDO >> Firebird fica impossível... Então, após varrer a internet atrás de solução, decidiram fazer via API; solução implementada no mesmo horário. As bibliotecas de Delphi, aparentemente, são mais ativas e com menos bugs, aparentemente, que algumas do laravel, especificamente de Firebird. Agora temos a solução... Mas queria um caminho menos trabalhoso para repassar tudo nos projetos...

Comment: Basicamente, criamos uma interface do banco de dados, onde poderemos configurar qualquer banco através dessa API. Se fossemos trabalhar do modo tradicional (não levar o servidor no cliente), não seria necessário tudo isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi construindo *endpoint* na *API* e ligando diretamente no *Controller* as chamadas. Lá eu construo os objetos e *esqueço* o *Eloquent* (Seria interessante conseguir implementar essa modificação, pois o MVC ficaria intacto em todo o projeto).
Mas em uma empresa que busca resultados, menos é mais. Acabei fazendo do jeito que eu sei ao invés de continuar buscando outras formas.
Quem sabe num futuro próximo eu resolva isso né? =D 
Por hora, é melhor entregar resultado rápido e manter o emprego. rsrs